# How can I perform a second grep on the files returned from a previous grep?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, grep

I often find myself searching through a bunch of code using grep in order to pin down what I'm looking for. Sometimes I get a list of files a little longer than I hoped. At this point I want to perform a second grep, but only searching through the files returned by the first grep search. Is there a way to do this? I basically want to cross-reference two grep searches and only get back the files with both results contained within them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
grep -lZ "first string" * | xargs -0 grep -l "second string"
```

- First `grep` will return the files containing `first string`.
- Second `grep` will do the same for `second string`, but over the results from the first `grep`.
- The `-Z` argument to grep and the `-0` argument to xargs work together to enable support for filenames that include spaces.

---

Edit - thanks to [Ajedi32](https://superuser.com/users/83682/ajedi32):

`xargs` lets you use the results from a command as the arguments to another.

From the [`xargs`'s Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), *xargs is a command on Unix and most Unix-like operating systems used to build and execute command lines from standard input.*

Comment: Awesome thank you. Can you enlighten me as to what `xargs` is?

Comment: @AlexFord - from the [`xarg`'s Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), *xargs is a command on Unix and most Unix-like operating systems used to build and execute command lines from standard input.*.  In other words, it allows you to use the results from a command as the standard input to another.  Try to use the same commands but without `xargs`, and you will see the problem (`grep -l "first string" * | grep -l "second string"`)

Comment: What is the problem with that command line? I don't have an OS X or Linux system at hand to test on.

Comment: @ntoskrnl - you will get a "`(standard input)`" message.  A good explanation is [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96462/mv-complains-about-standard-input-in-a-pipeline-that-filters-file-name-with-grep), from [Joseph R.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26909/joseph-r)

Comment: @jim "it allows you to use the results from a command as the standard input to another" No, that's what piping does. xargs lets you use the results from a command as the *arguments* to another.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - you are correct - my bad.  Edited answer :-) Thanks!